# How to use cvxpy for minimizing 3D model coordinates

Tags: opencv, optimization, computer-vision, cvxpy, convex-optimization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiTwz.png)
I'm trying to solve a convex objective function problem by using the cvxpy function in Python.

```
    X = cp.Variable((4,1))
    S = cp.Variable(1)
    constraints = [X[-1] == 1]
    obj = 0
    for i in range(len(img_list)):
        obj = obj + cp.norm(S * np.array([ip_list[i]]).T - p_list[i] @ X, p=2)
    obj = cp.Minimize(obj)
    problem = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
    result = problem.solve(solver = 'ECOS')
    sol_list.append(np.array(X.value))
    S_list.append(np.array(S.value))
```

After I run code, I got 11 solution 3D keypoint position X_i i=1,...,11
but this solution is wrong. When I calculate P @ X ,there are many error compare to 2d position

please tell me what's wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGJjW.jpg)